# Linear regression with interaction fails in the rms-package

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm playing around with interaction in the formula. I wondered if it's possible to do a regression with interaction for one of the two dummy variables. This seems to work in regular linear regression using the lm() function but with the ols() function in the rms package the same formula fails. Anyone know why?

**Here's my example**

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
regular_lm <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + gear + cyl:gear, data=mtcars)
summary(regular_lm)

regular_lm <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + gear + cyl:I(gear == "4"), data=mtcars)
summary(regular_lm)
```

And now the rms example

```
library(rms)

dd <- datadist(mtcars)
options(datadist = "dd")

regular_ols <- ols(mpg ~ wt + cyl + gear + cyl:gear, data=mtcars)
regular_ols

# Fails with:
#     Error in if (!length(fname) || !any(fname == zname)) { : 
#         missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
regular_ols <- ols(mpg ~ wt + cyl + gear + cyl:I(gear == "4"), data=mtcars)
```

This experiment might not be the wisest statistic to do as it seems that the estimates change significantly but I'm a little curious to why ols() fails since it should do the "same fitting routines used by lm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly, but it has to do with the way the formula is evaluated rather than with the way the fit is done once the model has been translated. Using `traceback()` shows that the problem occurs within `Design(eval.parent(m))`; using `options(error=recover)` gets you to the point where you can see that

```
Browse[1]> fname
[1] "wt"   "cyl"  "gear"
Browse[1]> zname
[1] NA
```

in other words, `zname` is some internal variable that hasn't been set right because the `Design` function can't quite handle defining the interaction between cylinders and the (gear==4) dummy on the fly.

This works though:

```
mtcars$cylgr <- with(mtcars,interaction(cyl,gear == "4"))
regular_ols <- ols(mpg ~ wt + cyl + gear + cylgr, data=mtcars)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've thought about creating the interaction variable but I'm a little scared that it'll interact with the Predict/contrast functions