# lrm fit vs glm fit for discontinuous function

Tags: r

I get an error when fitting using `lrm` (of `rms` package) whereas I don't using glm. I'd like to use the lrm function for the package associated validation and calibration capabilities.

Perhaps I'm confused in what I want out of my model: I expect very different outcome if a covariate is zero, vs if the outcome is non-zero. Much prefer to fit two terms rather than some single function to the data

```
 a= c(rep(0,10),rnorm(90,10,1)) # 10% outcomes=0, 90% clustered around 10.
 b= rnorm(100)>0
 mydataframe=data.frame(a,b)
 glm(b~I(a>0)+a,data=mydataframe,family='binomial') # no errors.
 lrm(b~I(a>0)+a,data=mydataframe)
```

> Error in if (!length(fname) || !any(fname == zname)) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Of course either glm or lrm works fine with just `glm(b~a, data=mydataframe)`, but shouldn't lrm work as well when a function of "a" is included twice? Or is there some singularity or implausible estimation that occurs?

Thanks in advance for any direction!

Comment: I think this earlier question is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562398/linear-regression-with-interaction-fails-in-the-rms-package

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jogo's comment, I think the problem is  only in the lack of a specific variable name in my formula. For whatever reason, lrm() doesn't handle it as well as glm(). Simply assigning a new variable to I(a>0) and including that variable instead in the model seems to remove the error:

```
 a= c(rep(0,10),rnorm(90,10,1)) # 10% outcomes=0, 90% clustered around 10.
 b= rnorm(100)>0
 mydataframe=data.frame(a,b)
 glm(b~I(a>0)+a,data=mydataframe,family='binomial') # no errors.
 mydataframe$k = I(a>0)
 lrm(b~k+a,data=mydataframe) # also works!
```